# How to increase the size limit of ELECTRON file size which is limited in window.localStorage?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, electron, electron-packager

I need to increase the file size which can be saved to the local system but this process(window.localStorage) limits the file size to 5MB/10MB. Please look into the code -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
  protected storage = window.localStorage;

  constructor() { }

  get(key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem(key));
  }

  set(key, value) {
    this.storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }
}
```

Comment: Use indexedDB instead. Has more storage capacity

Comment: can you give any sort of instruction for it @charlietfl

Comment: Numerous libraries you can use ... read yellow notes here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Answer (score 1):

The HTML standard doesn't allow the localstorage to be modified, it's hardcoded into the browser. Explain why you need to be able to do this so people can provide other solutions.

> User agents should limit the total amount of space allowed for storage areas, because hostile authors could otherwise use this feature to exhaust the user's available disk space.
>
> A mostly arbitrary limit of five megabytes per origin is suggested. Implementation feedback is welcome and will be used to update this suggestion in the future.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-localstorage

Comment: I need a JSON dump and there can images as well, so that dump data can be more than the limit of localStorage, so is there any package which can be used to remove the size restrictions , and if yes ,then how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: @sndpoffcl did u find the solution?